# script in bash two if condition and print in for loop

Tags: bash, for-loop, if-statement, tail

Hello im learning to script in bash, i trying to solve a little exercise.
The Exercise is this

> If the variable named "basenew" contains the contents of the variable
> named "valuebase".  "basenew" must contain more than 113,469
> characters.  If both conditions are met, the script must then print
> the last 20 characters of the variable "basenew".

My code is

```
#!/bin/bash

basenew="8dm7KsjU28B7v621Jls"
valuebase="ERmFRMVZ0U2paTlJYTkxDZz09Cg"

for i in {1..40}
do
    basenew=$(echo $basenew | base64)

    if [[ $basenew =~ $valuebase && ${#basenew} -ge 113469 ]] ; then
        echo $i
        echo $basenew | wc -c
        StrLen=`echo ${basenew} | wc -c`
        From=`expr $StrLen - 20`
        echo $basenew | cut -c ${From}-${StrLen}
    else
        echo "error"

    fi
done
```

But im stuck, because prints in the loop 28, and are the 20 last but isn't the correct answer.

Any advice to print the last 20 characters using tail -c 20?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps `"${basenew: -20: 20}"` (https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)

Comment: I try but giveme the same output in this code

```StrLen=`echo ${basenew} | wc -c`
From=`expr $StrLen - 20`
echo $basenew | cut -c ${From}-${StrLen}```

Comment: @joop: _"basenew" contains ... the variable named "valuebase"_  In your example, basenew is shorter than valuebase, and a longer string can never contain a shorter one, so you should expect _error_ here.

Comment: @joop: Do the variables always contain letters and digits only? If they can contain special characters, your approach may fail completely, because the right hand side of `=~` is treated as regex. You should test for substring, not regex match.

Comment: Keeping nontrivial amounts of data in memory is often a bad design, and often easy to avoid.

Comment: @user1934428 any example to implement this in the code?

Comment: Please post on Stackoverflow specific questions: If you have problems in particular with how to match a substring in a variable, ask about only this. Of course you are encouraged to show your current attempts. In your current question, you seem to ask only about extracting the last n characters from a string using the `tail` command.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think the value of `basenew` will change during the execution of your loop? You never assign it. But you assign `var` that you never use, could it be the issue? Yes it is, you need to update `basenew`, not the unused `var`.

There is another problem with your script: `cut` applies your character selection on each line of the input. `base64`, by default, splits the output in lines of 76 characters. So, after a while, you have many short lines. And as they all are much shorter than your specification `cut` would only print a lot of newlines, not the last 20 characters of the string. You could change the behaviour of `base64` with `base64 -w0` but it would also change the results of each iteration and you would probably never match the reference string.

Instead of piping `echo` in `cut` follow joop's suggestion: `"${basenew: -20: 20}"` expands as the 20 last characters of the value of `basenew`. Or, a bit simpler but equivalent: `"${basenew: -20}"`. Do not forget the space between `:` and `-20`, it is needed.

Finally, you could use more built-in bash constructs to avoid external commands (`wc`, `echo`, `cut`), use the modern `$(...)` instead of the old backticks, and use the arithmetic evaluation (`((...))`) instead of the obsolete `expr`. Try, maybe:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# file: foo.sh

basenew="8dm7KsjU28B7v621Jls"
valuebase="ERmFRMVZ0U2paTlJYTkxDZz09Cg"

for i in {1..40}; do
    basenew=$(echo "$basenew" | base64)
    if [[ $basenew =~ $valuebase ]] && (( ${#basenew} >= 113469 )) ; then
        printf '%d\n%d\n%s\n' "$i" "${#basenew}" "${basenew: -20}"
    else
        printf 'error\n'
    fi
done
```

Demo:

```sh
$ ./foo.sh
error
...
error
28
113469
U2paTlJYTkxDZz09Cg==
error
...
error
```

Comment: i try the code, but i get the same output, and the Exercise tookme like wrong output.
Is there any way to save the 28 round in the loop inside a .txt?

Comment: I just tested it and it worked exactly as you expect. Did you really copy-paste the whole script and did you run this one, not another? And yes, there is a way to store the successive values of `basenew` in a file. Just add `echo "$basenew" > "$i.txt"` after `basenew=$(echo "$basenew" | base64)`. Then look for the `1.txt`, `2.txt`... files

Comment: yes i try the code you post, that's why i don't understand because met both if.    The only hint i get in the exercise is  the use of tail -c 20, but this is making same function  `"${basenew: -20}"`

Comment: When you write "_i get the same output_", you mean that you see 40 times `error` instead of 27 times `error`, then `28`, `113469`, `U2paTlJYTkxDZz09Cg==` and again 12 times `error`?

Comment: "_The only hint i get in the exercise is the use of tail -c 20, but this is making same function "${basenew: -20}_": not exactly. If you try `echo "$basenew" | tail -c 20` you will get `2paTlJYTkxDZz09Cg==` plus a newline character, not `U2paTlJYTkxDZz09Cg==`. What are your specifications? Print the last 20 characters including the final newline or not including the final newline?

Comment: it say only print last 20 characters i make the code saving the $basenew in txt and then tail -c 20 and the answer is correct, but there are 19 characters.

Thanks a lot

Comment: There are 20 characters, but the last one is a newline, not an alphanumeric character. OK, then in the bash script, replace `"${basenew: -20}"` by `"${basenew: -19}"` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

*Any advice to print the last 20 characters using tail*

From the `tail` man-page:

> ```
>    -c, --bytes=[+]NUM
>          output the last NUM bytes; or use -c +NUM to output  starting  with
>          byte NUM of each file
> ```

Hence, if you have a variable `x`, you get the last 20 characters of it printed to stdout using

```
tail --bytes=20 <<<$x
```